# My Unity scene opens as a white checkerboard image of the terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene, terrain, invisible

I am able to open my unity project and base scene on any computer other than my laptop. When I open the main scene on my laptop I am greeted with all of the terrain being a white checkerboard. All of the gameObjects show on the side bar but are invisible in the scene and game views. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated as I have looked for the answer everywhere.

[image: View]

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow! Can you create minimal example of code illustrating your problem? Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for inspiration

Comment: I receive a whole lot of errors when I initially open my project as well

Answer (score 0):

Your image which you uploaded points that you are viewing your game in Scene mode rather than game mode. In your **scene mode** the rendering has been switched to **Baked Lightmap** or one of the other modes in **Baked Global Illumination**. By default Unity Scene modes are kept in **Shaded** in **Shading mode**. ie the one where we see our scene same as Game scene. To get back to shaded mode Find the Dropdown button below Scene Tab and select shaded mode.

Comment: Its actually in shaded mode but thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the workaround for this same problem on mine: Hopefully your is similar.

After I upgraded my Unity version to the latest and it updated the project, it created a _TerrainAutoUpgrade folder in "Assets". I followed my normal source control rules, which was to check in most of this folder but to ignore the .meta files (allowing the computer that cloned my repository to generate its own).

Turns out, that didn't work. The meta files generated on the second computer, the "mainObjectFileID" in the meta file was set to 0.

I fixed it by manually copying over the _TerrainAutoUpgrade folder from the working machine to the non-working one. Clearly this is a bug in Unity, but at least this got me around it.

Comment: FYI, you should definitely put .meta files into version control as well, since they contain the GUID of the asset along with other import settings. Otherwise all links between assets are broken on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem where my terrain was looking like a checkerboard. I found out that I was missing the terrain layers when I went to the paint tab. I was able to solve it by replacing the layers with terrain layers I already had and replacing the textures.